# What kind of object does a linq statement return?

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

This might be a really stupid and obvious question, but I'm very new to Linq.  In my Data Access Layer class I have this method:

```
static public ? GetAllUrls()
        {



            using (MonitoredUrlsEntities mu = new MonitoredUrlsEntities())
            {


                var query = from urlTbl in mu.UrlLists
                            join histTbl in mu.Histories on
                            urlTbl.ID equals histTbl.UrlID
                            select new
                            {
                                urlTbl.Url,
                                urlTbl.UrlTitle,
                                urlTbl.UrlType,
                                urlTbl.Frequency,
                                urlTbl.Active,
                                urlTbl.LastChangeDate,
                                urlTbl.LastCheckDate,
                                histTbl.DateRun,
                                histTbl.HashValue
                            };

                  return query.ToList();


            }
```

The question mark is there because I have no idea what type of object a linq statement returns.  I just a list that I can loop through.

Comment: Depends on the statement, but generally IQueryable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can't return anonymous types from a method (like others have said). Create a concrete type and new one of those up. Your return type is `IEnumerable<YourType>` as below:

```
// NOTE: I do not know the actual types of these properties, YMMV
public sealed class UrlHistoryList
{
    public string Url { get; set; }
    public string UrlTitle { get; set; }
    public string UrlType { get; set; }
    public int Frequency { get; set; }
    public bool Active { get; set; }
    public DateTime LastChangeDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime LastCheckDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateRun { get; set; }
    public int HashValue { get; set; }
}

static public IEnumerable<UrlHistoryList> GetAllUrls()
        {



            using (MonitoredUrlsEntities mu = new MonitoredUrlsEntities())
            {


                var query = from urlTbl in mu.UrlLists
                            join histTbl in mu.Histories on
                            urlTbl.ID equals histTbl.UrlID
                            select new UrlHistoryList
                            {
                                Url = urlTbl.Url,
                                UrlTitle = urlTbl.UrlTitle,
                                UrlType = urlTbl.UrlType,
                                Frequency = urlTbl.Frequency,
                                Active = urlTbl.Active,
                                LastChangeDate = urlTbl.LastChangeDate,
                                LastCheckDate = urlTbl.LastCheckDate,
                                DateRun = histTbl.DateRun,
                                HashValue = histTbl.HashValue
                            };

                  return query.ToList();


            }
```

Comment: this is perfect! create a class and return it from method.

Comment: I get a "Cannot initialize type 'ChangeDetection.UrlHistoryList' with a collection initializer because it does not implement 'System.Collections.IEnumerable'.  Any ideas why it would say that?

Comment: @broke: Because Jesse has accidentally given you the syntax for a collection initializer, not an object initializer. That should be `... new UrlHistoryList { Url = urlTbl.Url, UrlTitle = urlTbl.UrlTitle ... `

Answer (score 11):

As others have noted, the results of this particular query involve an *anonymous type*. You therefore cannot annotate the method as returning the exact type of the local variable, because *you can't type the name of that type*, because it doesn't have a name; that's what "anonymous" means.

You can say that the method returns `IEnumerable<object>` or `IEnumerable` or `object` or even `dynamic`, but probably the better thing to do is to **make the query return a sequence of nominal type in the first place.**

More generally: as others have noted, a query *typically* has some sort of `IEnumerable` or `IQueryable` type in practice. However, it is important to realize that a LINQ expression does not necessarily have any particular type. LINQ is implemented as a *syntactic transformation*, not a *semantic* transformation. When you say:

```
var query = from c in customers select c.Name;
```

the compiler translates that blindly into:

```
var query = customers.Select(c=>c.Name);
```

The type of `query` is whatever the method `Select` happens to return. It could be `int`! It almost certainly is not, because that would be *dumb*, but if some perverse person decided to make a method called `Select` that returns an `int`, then query would be of type `int`.

As it turns out, I am just such a perverse person; I give an example of using LINQ to manipulate integers here:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/12/07/query-transformations-are-syntactic.aspx

Comment: Thanks for the info! Your blog rocks btw.

Answer (score 6):

you are using anonymous type in LINQ expression - and, as documentation states:

> You cannot declare a field, a property, an event, or the return type
>   of a method as having an anonymous type.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397696.aspx

Comment: And to get around that, create a type with properties/fields that you're selecting and return (a list of) that instead.

Answer (score 4):

It returns list of anonymous type and you cannot return anonymous type from method (perhaps if you use dynamic you can but it is mess). Instead of using anonymous type create a new class with all properties and fill it in the projection:

```
var query = from urlTbl in mu.UrlLists
            join histTbl in mu.Histories on
                urlTbl.ID equals histTbl.UrlID
            select new YourNewType
            {
                Url = urlTbl.Url,
                UrlTitle = urlTbl.UrlTitle,
                UrlType = urlTbl.UrlType,
                Frequency = urlTbl.Frequency,
                Active = urlTbl.Active,
                LastChangeDate = urlTbl.LastChangeDate,
                LastCheckDate = urlTbl.LastCheckDate,
                DateRun = histTbl.DateRun,
                HashValue = histTbl.HashValue
            };
```

Now your method can return `IEnumerable<YourNewType>`

Comment: @Jason: But in such case you will completely lose access to inner data.

Comment: Huh? No. You can cast or use reflection.

Comment: @Jason: casting to a type you cannot name is difficult -- not impossible, but tricky. And using reflection is ugly and error-prone. If you were going to do that, you'd be better off simply using `dynamic`. But the best thing to do is what Ladislav suggests: return a sequence of nominal type.

Comment: @Jason: And what type do you want to cast it?

Comment: @Eric Lippert: I'm NOT arguing that this is the right way to do it (please see my [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9587692/45914) for proof of that). I'm merely pointing out that `dynamic` is not the only way as the answer initially stated before being edited that `dynamic` was the only way without resorting to a nominal type.

Comment: You can cast it to an instance of the same anonymous type.

Answer (score 3):

Well, it's an `List<T>` where `T` is a certain anonymous type that you can't say in your own code (anonymous types are given unspeakable names).

It's done intentionally that way; it's generally a mistake to spread anonymous types outside of local uses.

You should make a concrete type, instead of using an anonymous type. Call it `Foo`. Then your return type would be `List<Foo>`.

Comment: *"anonymous types are given unspeakable names"* - such as `Voldemort`?

Answer (score 2):

Typically a LINQ statement returns an IEnumerable/IQueryable, thus the reason you are able to use .ToList(). In your case, you are returning a List because of the .ToList(), though.

If you remove the ToList(), I would have your return as IEnumerable if all you are looking to do is loop through the results

Answer (score 2):

It returns `IQueryable<T>` where `T` is the anonymous object defined in the `select new` portion of the query.

In the end it is returned as a `List<T>`

The method signature should probably be: `public static List<dynamic> GetAllUrls()`
because `static public ? GetAllUrls()` appears to be invalid.

Answer (score 1):

Try `IEnumerable`

If you drop the .ToList() it would be `IQueryable`

Answer (score 1):

In this example you're returning an anonymous object base on type `IQueryable<T>` so could iterate the list like this

```
foreach (var item in query)
{
     //you could access to each attribute of the object like this

    string url = item.Url
    string urlTittle = item.UrlTittle
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As some answers have noted, you're having trouble with the method's return type because it is an anonymous type.  There are a few tricks you could use to get around that; they mostly involve defining the anonymous type at the call site of `GetAllUrls`, defining `GetAllUrls` as a generic method, and allowing the compiler's type inference to do the rest.

In this case, though, it's probably better to make sure that EF and your database have a relationship defined between URLs and histories, and use EF to get the histories from each URL (or vice versa).  For example:

```
foreach (var url in mu.UrlLists)
    foreach (var history in url.Histories)
    {
        var obj = new {    
                          url.Url,    
                          url.UrlTitle,    
                          url.UrlType,    
                          url.Frequency,    
                          url.Active,    
                          url.LastChangeDate,    
                          url.LastCheckDate,    
                          history.DateRun,    
                          history.HashValue    
                      };
        // do something with obj
  }
```

or just

```
foreach (var url in mu.UrlLists)
    foreach (var history in url.Histories)
        //do something with url and history
```